# Im making a project where im using django as backend and react as frontend and im receiving following error when i run server in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-settings

The frontend is supposed to be showing products but its not and the error in django is this:

[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCjRE.jpg)

[Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWL4E.jpg)

X-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------X

```
These are few important components of my settings.py file where i think the error is




INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app.apps.AppConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.Common.Middleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

/

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

I tried searching for error but havent found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
'django.middleware.common.Common.Middleware',
```

to

```
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
```